# How to run stack ghci on WSL?

Tags: haskell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, haskell-stack

I installed Haskell stack in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on Windows 10).
After that, I successfully installed stack using command `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`

However, after I tried to run gchi I got this error:

```
et@DESKTOP-D0DE6C4:~$ stack ghci
Writing implicit global project config file to: /home/et/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Using latest snapshot resolver: lts-18.16
Preparing to install GHC (tinfo6) to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Downloaded ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7.
ghc-pkg: Couldn't open database /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d for modification: {handle: /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d/package.cache.lock}: hLock: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
make[1]: *** [ghc.mk:985: install_packages] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:51: install] Error 2
Received ExitFailure 2 when running
Raw command: /usr/bin/make install
Run from: /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7.temp/ghc-8.10.7/


Error: Error encountered while installing GHC with
         make install
         run in /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7.temp/ghc-8.10.7/

       The following directories may now contain files, but won't be used by stack:
         - /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7.temp/
         - /home/et/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/

       For more information consider rerunning with --verbose flag

Installing GHC ...
et@DESKTOP-D0DE6C4:~$
```

**--verbose** flag did not help as it shows the same error again.
I did not manage to Google anything useful on that.

Comment: What you've done should work, and works for me on WSL. Have you tried deleting `/home/et/.stack` and starting over, in case it's some hiccup that happened once and left a corrupted directory?

Comment: Are you on WSL 1 or WSL 2?

Comment: Thank you for advice provided. I found that I am on WSL 1.
`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         1`
I will upgrade to version 2 to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I installed WSL 2  as explained here [WSL | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) and after that I successfully installed stack ghci. Thanks [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) for the idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).